# Encountered two children with the same key. keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

> I am fetching github users in my reactjs web app. On searching user
>   second time I find the pagination appearing twice on each click.
>
> Below is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const Pagination = props => {

  var pagesMap = [];

  function populatePagesMap() {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.pages; i++) {
      pagesMap.push(i + 1);
    }
  }
  populatePagesMap();

  function funcCallback(e) {
    this.props.callbackFromApp(e.target.id)
  }

  var pagesNumber = pagesMap.map(d => (
    <li className="page-item" key={d} onClick={this.funcCallback}>
      <a className="page-link" id={d}> {d} </a>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
      <ul className="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-end">
        {pagesNumber}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: Are there any duplicate elements in pagesMap?

Comment: This code might be greatly simplified but at first sight it seems correct, how do you use this component? Maybe the problem is in its container, not here.

Comment: <PaginationComponent
          pages={noOfPage()}
          callbackFromApp={this.getPageNo} />

Comment: I am passing just number of pages and selected page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should empty your pagesMap array before refilling so code for populatePagesMap should be :

```
  function populatePagesMap() {
    pagesMap = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < props.pages; i++) {
      pagesMap.push(i + 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: An accepted answer with a negative vote total. That's a first for me.

Answer (score 0):

try including **Index** in **key construction**, this will make it unique.

```
  var pagesNumber = pagesMap.map((d,index) => (
    <li className="page-item" key={d+index} onClick={this.funcCallback}>
      <a className="page-link" id={d}> {d} </a>
    </li>
  ));
```

Don't use only the **index** anytime because it's an [anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318), you can use it along **id** there is no harm.

Comment: This does not solve duplication. Key value remains same